# Make newcommands display in side bar

Tags: macros

Usually, when we define sections or subsections, it appears in side bar of PDF viewer, but when I define a `\newcommand`, it doesn't seem to appear in side bar.

As an example, in the below snippet:

```
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\section{Another Section}
\newsubsection{Another subsection}
```

Here I have defined a `\newcommand` for `\newsubsection`.
In the PDF viewer side panel, I can see the following:

[image]

How can I make the `\newsubsection` appear in the same way as the `\subsection` in above example. The goal is when a software scans the document, it shouldn't miss the content defined by my `\newsubsection`.

The `\newsubsection` is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\newsubsection}[1]{
\fontsize{9pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries\uppercase {#1} \normalfont
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! You mean PDF bookmarks, right?

Comment: More like an Index? I just want to get it included in the structure of PDF.

Comment: The easiest solution is to define `\newsubsection` in terms of `\subsection` rather than the manual, ad hoc formatting commands you have used. But note: It has nothing to do with the 'software' (what is this? the PDF viewer?) 'scanning' the document.

Comment: in order to give an accurate answer, we need to know what document class you're using.  different document classes define section headings differently, and the `titlesec` package isn't always compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sf, compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand{\newsubsection}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  % Here is an arbitrary formatting redefinition just for this example
  \titleformat*{\subsection}{\LARGE\itshape\bfseries}%
  % Note this massively simplifies what you can do with \newsubsection compared to \subsection; of course it is possible to preserve \subsection functionality if needed
  \subsection{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\section{Another Section}
\newsubsection{Another subsection}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Or, if you can't use `titlesec`, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newsubsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0mm}%
  {-\baselineskip} % beforeskip
  {1\baselineskip} % afterskip
  {\LARGE\itshape\bfseries}}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\section{Another Section}
% You can use \newsection[<short form>]{<full heading>}
\newsubsection[123456]{123456 Another subsection}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```